# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined while using multiDatePicker library?

Tags: jquery

I am using multiDatePicker in my page, but its showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
<script src="http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"/>
```

```
<body>

    <div>
      <input id="datePick" name="calendar"/>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
});
</script>


</body>
```

Please suggest what I am missing or why this error is showing?

Comment: You seem to have multiple jQuery libraries referenced? You should not have that.

Comment: You have 2 references to different versions of jquery...just remove the last one and it should be ok :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I removed the last one but still the same problem.

Comment: You are misssing some closing script-tags there as well as the mentioned double reference. Close your first three script tags as well

Comment: @Joscha She is using an empty tag not a container tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one jquery min library at before UI date picker library like that.

Note: you also needed required resources are:

1. jquery.min.js
2. jquery-ui.min.js
3. jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js and
4. jquery-ui.css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datePick').multiDatesPicker();
 });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<div>
  <input id="datePick" name="calendar"/>
</div>
```

**== Thanks ==**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how is that possible. By using ur code now its showing one more error 404 for the multiDatePicker.js

Comment: But still the problem is same $ is not defined.

Comment: You can review again my ans I change the UI datepicker CDN URL  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-ui-multidatespicker@1.6.6/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.min.js"

Comment: Your code solved my previous problem but showing in console some other error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'multiDatesPicker' of undefined".

Comment: I edited my code while explaining my problem. Please check there.

Comment: You can review again my ans plz